# Update table with random DECIMAL number within a range (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to update the column ItemValue of table Items with a decimal value generated randomly within 1 and 100 (a different value for each row). Each value should have two (random) digits.

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(
    ItemID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ItemValue decimal(13, 4) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Items PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ItemID ASC)
)

INSERT INTO Items(ItemValue) VALUES (0)
INSERT INTO Items(ItemValue) VALUES (0)
INSERT INTO Items(ItemValue) VALUES (0)
INSERT INTO Items(ItemValue) VALUES (0)

-- Now, I want to update the table
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use **RAND** to generate random number. But there is one problem - **RAND** is executed only once per query, so all your rows will contain same random value. You can use **CHECKSUM(NEWID())** to make it random per row, like this

```
UPDATE items
SET itemValue = ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (100), 2)
```

Comment: Ok, but I also need two random digits

Comment: Sorry, missed it. Updated my answer: Round now takes 2 as second argument, not 0.

Comment: UPDATE items
SET itemValue = ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (100), 2)

Comment: relating to updating all of the rows, you could try

        UPDATE items
        SET itemValue = ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (100), 2)
        WHERE primary_key > 0; 
which will update everything in the db.

Answer (score 6):

You could use this snippet to generate random decimal values:

```
CONVERT( DECIMAL(13, 4), 10 + (30-10)*RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
```

This will generate random decimal numbers between 10 and 30.

Comment: I think you missed a closing bracket.